# How to get frequency of row value order in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
User   Marketing_Channel
A      Direct marketing
A      Email
A      Paid Search
B      Email
B      Paid Search
C      Email
C      Paid Search
```

I would like to know the frequencies of path to purchase in the form of dictionary, which is the frequencies of row value of marketing channel column in specific order. For the dataframe above, the answer should be

```
{'Direct marketing -> 'Email -> Paid Search':  1,
     'Email -> Paid Search': 2}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Marketing_Channel': ['Direct_Marketing', 'Email', 'Paid_Search', 'Email', 'Paid_Search', 'Email', 'Paid_Search']})

counts = df.groupby('User')['Marketing_Channel'].apply(list).str.join(" -> ").value_counts().to_dict()
```

To break it down:

`groupby('User')['Marketing_Channel'].apply(list)` to aggregate the values of `Marketing_Channel` into a list of values for each `User`

`str.join(" -> ")` to join the lists into a path per the OP

`.value_counts().to_dict()` to count the number of unique paths and convert to a dictionary.

For this example data, `counts` contains:

```
{'Email -> Paid_Search': 2, 'Direct_Marketing -> Email -> Paid_Search': 1}
```

Comment: Nice one , you can directly agg the join instead of apply+str.join and sort false on value counts for exact match of output: `df.groupby('User')['Marketing_Channel'].agg(" -> ".join).value_counts(sort=False).to_dict()`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```python
import pandas as pd

#initialize the data
x = pd.DataFrame({'User':['A','A','A','B','B','C','C'],'Marketing_Channel':['Marketing_Channel','Email','Paid Search','Email','Paid Search','Email','Paid Search']})

#grouping by user to get the user journey
y = x.groupby('User').agg({'Marketing_Channel': '->'.join}).reset_index()

#group by channel to get the count
z = y.groupby('Marketing_Channel').count()

#make a json out of it
z.to_json()
```